# How to Create a Pandas DataFrame from multiple list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, pandas, xlsxwriter

I want to create a pandas dataframe using the two list of dictionaries below:

```
country_codes = [
    {
        "id": 92,
        "name": "93",
        "position": 1,
        "description": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "id": 93,
        "name": "355",
        "position": 2,
        "description": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "id": 94,
        "name": "213",
        "position": 3,
        "description": "Algeria"
    },
    {
        "id": 95,
        "name": "1-684",
        "position": 4,
        "description": "American Samoa"
    }
]
```

```
gender = [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Female"
   },
   {
      "id": 3
      "name": "Male"
   }
]
```

The dataframe should have two columns: `Gender` and `Country Code`. The values for gender will be from the gender variable while the value for country code will be from the country code variable.

I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(
        zip(
            gender,
            country_codes
        )
    ),
    columns=[
        "name"
        "description"
    ]
).rename({
    "name": "Gender",
    "description": "Country"
}))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('my_excel_file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sample_sheet", index=False)
writer.save()
```

But after running the script, the excel file was not populated.

The expected output is have the excel sheet (screenshot attached) populated with the data in those list of dictionaries I declared above
[image]

Comment: what is the explicit expected output?

Comment: Hi @mozway, I have edited the original post to include what the expected output is supposed to be

Comment: So you want empty columns? Please provide the **exact output that matches the provided input** ;)

Comment: Apologies @mozway, 
I do not want empty columns; I want them populated, added the exact output that matches the provided input :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': pd.DataFrame(gender)['name'],
                   'country': pd.DataFrame(country_codes)['description']})
```

Output:

```
   gender         country
0  Female     Afghanistan
1    Male         Albania
2     NaN         Algeria
3     NaN  American Samoa
```

Comment: I got `ValueError: array length 0 does not match index length 2`

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? This weekend fine with the given dictionaries. Which pandas version do you use?